# C++ program error Libxml2

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

What is wrong with this program?

I have "`/home/praktyka/projects/svgreader/main.cpp:55:31: error: ‘xmlNode’ has no member named ‘d’`"
error, please help

I dont know how to fix error

```
    xmlDoc         *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode        *root_element = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr      cur;
    xmlChar        *key;
    xmlAttrPtr     attr;
    const char     *Filename = "/home/praktyka/Dokumenty/drogi.svg";
    xmlChar        *d;    



cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
     if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->, (const xmlChar *)"d"))) {
        d = xmlGetProp(cur, (const xmlChar *)"d");
        printf("d: %s\n", d);
        xmlFree(d);
    }

  }
```

I want to see d:

```
<svg>
    <g>
       <path d="11"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `xmlNode` structure doesn't have a member named `d`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Have you made sure your element has a member name 'd'?

Comment: <svg>
    <g>
       <path d="11"/>
    </g> I want see d in terminal
</svg>

Comment: @user3520459, then look for element `***d***` and not `d`. Also, make sure your child node is actually pointing to that element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says: [structure xmlNode has no member "d"](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNode). If you want to compare the content of the node, use the member "content":

```
xmlStrcmp(cur->content, (const xmlChar *)"d"))
```

Comment: thanks ,but now I have "Segmentation fault"

Comment: You need to check whether cur is NULL.